# Is it ok to use observerForever() for a LiveData, does it not cause memory leaks? and should I unregister it somewhere in activity?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I created a custom liveData and that has a contentObserver, if I use observerForever on this content Observer does it not cause any memory leaks? and would like to know how safe is observerForever and what other pre-cautions I should take.

Comment: the docs say: *"Adds the given observer to the observers list. This call is similar to observe(LifecycleOwner, Observer) with a LifecycleOwner, which is always active. This means that the given observer will receive all events and will never be automatically removed. **You should manually call removeObserver(Observer) to stop observing this LiveData.**"*

Comment: it should be `@onDestroy` ideally. But, @pskink . any realtime use case for `observerForever()` ?

Comment: @SantanuSur when you use `MediatorLiveData` or `Tramsformations.*map()` methods you use `observerForever` under the hood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `removeObserver()` without which the observer will never be removed and depending on your implementation you may get memory leaks.